# event.PreventDefault on Gmail Send button

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I have added a click listener to the Gmail "Send" button and am using `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropogation()` to try and stop the email from sending, however, the email is still sending and the `try catch` blocks arent registering any errors.

```
$("div:contains('Send')").last().click(function(event){
    try{
        console.log("preventing default");
        event.preventDefault();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    try{
        console.log("stopping propogation");
        event.stopPropagation();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    alert("Hello");
});
```

This is the code I am using, I'd appreciate any input on why this isn't stopping the event execution.

Comment: Use the options provided by the API instead of _monkey-patch_

Comment: @Irtza.QC is your issue solved?

Comment: Oh yeah. Ages ago. Event.stoppropogation() and event.preventdefault() togethor

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you those two things,

event.preventDefault() will prevent the default actions of event source. For example, on click of Anchor, navigation to another page.

Please have a look at http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Next, event.stopPropagation() will prevent event to get triggered by parent node to child node

Also have a look at https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

In any case, javascript function you have written will be executed.

Comment: "why isnt it working? " means?? ..  if alert("hello") is working, then it is working as expected. Neither event.preventDefault() nor event.stopPropagation() is like return statment.

Comment: Hope it will explain more for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false?rq=1